# How do I split the XML in Mule Anypoint?

Tags: mule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">

    <mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="http://www.cpscreen.com/schemas"/>
    </mulexml:namespace-manager>

    <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
            <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
            <import class="org.mule.util.ArrayUtils" />
        </expression-language>
    </configuration>

    <flow name="user_provisions_-_xml_postFlow1" doc:name="user_provisions_-_xml_postFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:/temp/mule" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="in_(.*).csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[java.util.List items =  new java.util.ArrayList( Arrays.asList( payload.split("\n") ));
items.remove(0);;

java.lang.String listString = '';

for  (String s : items) {
    listString += s + "\n";
}

payload=listString.trim();]]></expression-component>

        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="46908" path="userprovision" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <splitter expression="#[xpath('//UpdateUserRequest')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>

        <logger message="Here is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I am getting like,

```
WARN  2014-09-10 15:30:27,181 [[user_provisions_-_xml_post].user_provisions_-_xml_postFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter: Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression
```

**Update** :

I got where the issue is but I could resolve the split issue. Because of `namespace` in the XML splitter does not evaluate the split expression...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UpdateUserRequests xmlns="http://www.cpscreen.com/schemas">
    <UpdateUserRequest userId="Test" account="Test" password="Test">
        <User>
            <Account id="4">34567</Account>
            <UserId>Test</UserId>
            <Profile>Admin</Profile>
            <PersonName>
                <GivenName>Sahak</GivenName>
                <FamilyName>Kn</FamilyName>
            </PersonName>
        </User>
    </UpdateUserRequest>
    <UpdateUserRequest userId="Test" account="Test" password="Test">
        <User>
            <Account id="5">12345</Account>
            <UserId>Test</UserId>
            <Profile>Admin</Profile>
            <PersonName>
                <GivenName>Arun</GivenName>
                <FamilyName>Kumar</FamilyName>
            </PersonName>
        </User>
    </UpdateUserRequest>
</UpdateUserRequests>
```

If I remove `xmlns="http://www.cpscreen.com/schemas"` it is splitting to multiple

How do I add the spit expression if there is a namespace in the xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following expression to split the xml with namespace.

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath('//ns0:UpdateUserRequest')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
```

The above expression works considering the "ns0"  namespace is added in the Mule MXL namespace manager.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should directly use the splitter after the file inbound endpoint ... 
This expression works for splitting CSV file :-

```
<splitter expression="#[StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r')]" doc:name="Splitter_For_MultipleRow"/>
```

And if your CSV files have a column headers like Name, Age etc .. you can use this :-

```
<splitter expression="#[rows=StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r');ArrayUtils.subarray(rows,1,rows.size())]" doc:name="Splitter_For_MultipleRow"></splitter>
```

Comment: I can not do that, because I am sending the CSV data to other ESB (Because Mule data mapper is paid) and it returns me xml. I need to split the xml and read

Comment: I got where I am facing issue .. updated the project. Namespace is there in the xml that is the reason it did not split